# Increasing concurrent invocations in Jee6 application on Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, websphere, java-ee-6

we are developing a JEE6 application running on Websphere application server 8.5.5.x.

The application consists of a JAX-RS webservice, several EJBs and a JPA-abstraction layer for a DB2 database.
We are using Java 8 lambdas with parallel()-calls.

The problem is reported in CA Introscope Wily.

Since a few weeks we are facing the problem that the concurrent invocations of our stateless EJBs are increasing dramatically overtime.
This phenomenon does not have any impact on the performance of the application nor does it have any impact on the application server itself.
But our admins get scared :)

The code looks totally insuspicious and we don't have an idea where to look for.

So, here are my questions:
- Has anyone experienced such a behaviour before?
- Does anyone have a hint where to search usually in such a case?